# PHP Wordpress Datetime A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, wordpress, api, timezone

Good morning,
I have the following error message in the log:

`PHP Warning:  A non-numeric value encountered in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/coworker/coworker.php on line 137,`

I am trying to determine the time zone differences between Germany and UTC time. The result would be +2
Determine difference:

```
        $tz = 'Europe/Berlin'; // Our Timezone
        $tz_obj = new DateTimeZone($tz);
        $today = new DateTime("now", $tz_obj);
        $ts1 = $today->format($df); // local German Time
        $ts2 = gmdate($df); // UTC Time
        $ts3 = $ts1-$ts2; // Get the difference +2
```

I add this time to my variable:

```
 $person_datum_api = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($person_datum_aenderung. ' + ' . $ts3 . 'hours')); //Time from API + difference
```

Comment: This error could be on line `$ts3 = $ts1-$ts2;` when you do a mathematic operation on a non-numeric value then it comes. You need to convert a string to an integer or float before performing a mathematical operation.

Comment: @Vijay Hardaha
Thx a lot, i changed this line `$ts3 = intval($ts1)-intval($ts2);` and the warning has disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Is Working fine, please check this link.
http://tpcg.io/_8XDG2R

```
<?php
    $tz = 'Europe/Berlin'; // Our Timezone
    $df = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
    $tz_obj = new DateTimeZone($tz);
    $today = new DateTime("now", $tz_obj);
    $ts1 = $today->format($df); // local German Time
    $ts2 = gmdate($df); // UTC Time
    $ts3 = $ts1-$ts2; // Get the difference +2 
    $person_datum_api = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($person_datum_aenderung. ' + ' . $ts3 . 'hours')); //Time from API + difference
    echo $person_datum_api;
?>
```

Comment: It works, however there is a PHP warning that fills up the log file